# Exponential diophantine equation only need a single solution

Tags: cryptography, exponential-diophantine-equations

Hello can someone please help me find a formula for at least one integer solution to the following without brute force

$Y = ((g^x)-A)/p$

Where $g,p,A$ are constants, $P$ is a large prime, $Y$ and $X$ need to be integers

The solutions to the DH problem lie in points in this graph where $Y$ is an integer and $x$ is an integer.
Actually $Y$ is $\lfloor(g^x/p)\rfloor$ which is always an integer which is why for any point in this graph where both $x$ and $Y$ are integers you find a correct solution to the DH problem ie you can reverse the $g^{x}\operatorname{mod} p=A$.

Wondering if it's even possible.
Does anyone know if it has been solved or if its just not possible without brute force?

Thank you

Comment: If you assume that $g,A$ both relatively prime to $p$, then some  solution $x$ in $\{1,2,\cdots,[p-1]\}$ would have to exist.  
Do you characterize this approach as *brute force*, which is therefore outlawed?

Comment: So in this case you still can't find a single value to x or set of values without trying multiple solutions. We know there is an x between 1 and p-1 that will satisfy the equation infact if we just take that equation and apply mod 1 if the answer is zero then that is the solution to our problem so if you can solve (((g^x)-A)/p) mod 1 = 0 you are there its just i am not sure how to do it ?

Comment: My knowledge of Number Theory is limited.  Given the general case of $g,A$ relatively prime to $p$, I am unaware of any shortcut.  For example, if $(g,A,p) = (3,23,47)$ I am unaware of any shortcut to manually checking each of $\{3^1, 3^2, \cdots, 3^{(46)}\}$ to find the element $r$ such that $3^r \equiv 23\pmod{47}.$  Somebody who knows more Number Theory than I do might know of such a shortcut; I have never heard of one.